# How would you search for an obituary for someone with a common name?

Tags: military-records, death-records

My dearest friend died recently in March 2021, but he has a common 1st, middle, and last name. All three could be considered as basic first names.

I have made endless and extensive searches, and investigated on just about every site, paid for as well as free that I can think of, but I cannot get back any details about his death. I've been able to round up some general information on him, {past phone numbers, addresses, and some family members} but there's nothing regarding his passing. Not only that, but I ended up having to go through the LACO Coroner's Office and his autopsy results are being mailed to me. They told me it's going to take anywhere from 8 to 12 weeks to receive them. I cannot seem to discover any of his multiple marriage certificates or his military service records. However, I did find his birth and Christening certificates. I have, well, at least to my knowledge, all of his important info, such as D.O. B, the date he died, location of where he was born and passed away, driver's license, mother's maiden name, last 4 of his Social Security, among other identifying information.
I tried entering his name with apostrophes, his entire full name, city and state of where he died at. Like I said, some of his info shows up through generic searches, but nothing on his military, marriages, divorces, children, or death.

Is there anything else that could be suggested?

Comment: Obituaries are printed only if someone writes them and (usually) pays to have published. It's possible that no one wrote one for him. As for the marriage and military service records, those may be recent enough to still be sealed, available only to his descendants and close family.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: @shoover, that's the basis of a really useful answer about researching very recent events.